# How to start document with empty page followed by table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, double-sided, blank-page

In a book class document, I am trying to insert one empty page before the table of contents.

I tried with the following code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}\null\newpage
    \tableofcontents
    ...
\end{document}
```

But the code produces :

1. Empty page
2. Plain page
3. Table of contents

How can I insert just one empty page before the table of contents? Why doesn't the code produce what I expected?

Comment: I think the book class always wants to put the contents page on an odd page number, since in a book, that is on the right-hand page. Thus, when skipping a page, the book class will want to skip an extra page to get to an odd page. You could probably fool it with fudging the page number, but you might not like that solution either.

Comment: Sure enough, `\setcounter{page}{0}` after `\begin{document}` will do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per my original comment, the book class always wants to put the contents page on an odd page number, since in a book, that is on the right-hand page. Thus, when skipping a page, the book class will want to skip an extra page to get to an odd page. You can fool it by fudging the page number.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{0}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \tableofcontents
    ...
\end{document}
```

p.s.  This will put the Contents on a page numbered as `1`, even though it is the second page of the document.

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy to have the table-of-contents on page 2, then it sounds like you don't much care about the default setting of the `book` class, which dictates that the table-of-contents always starts on an odd-numbered page.

In which case, you can turn off this setting by giving the `oneside` option. Then your code does what you want. Note that this also means that chapters can now start on even or odd pages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{book}
\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}\null\newpage
    \tableofcontents
    ...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want but I am using this code to insert an empty page between title and table of contents:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,%
               twoside,%
               cleardoublepage=empty]%
               {book}
\title{title}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \cleardoublepage

    \tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest using this method. Fudging with page numbers: not a fan. And if you are writing a book you would want to keep the twosided style for estetic reasons.